# jquery select change event fire only one time

Tags: php, jquery, html, yii

Following is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        //jQuery('select[name="Vendor"]').on('change', function(){
        jQuery('select[name="Vendor"]').change(function(){

            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            alert("Selected Text: " + selectedValue);
              if(this.value ==2){
                jQuery('.grid_data').show();
              }else{
                jQuery('.grid_data_rel').show();
              }
        });
    //});
</script>
```

When i change select value event only occur for one time not alert showing on second time.

Html is coming from yii grid view like

```
 'filter'=>array('1'=>"Recomonded",'2'=>"Related"),  this is html in code and i used in yii frame work.
```

so here i can not see my static html code it's coming from gridview in yii.

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT product_id,product_name FROM `user_master` as u 
                                        INNER JOIN product_detail as p 
                                        ON p.vendor_id = u.u_id WHERE p.vendor_id =2";
    $result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();


$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-master-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'u_id',
        // 'product_id',
        // 'ut_id',
        // 'country_id',
        'fullname',
        // 'ur.role_name',
        array(
            'header' => 'Role Name',
            'name' => 'ur_id',
            'value' => '$data->ur->role_name',
        ),

        array(
            'header' => 'Product Name',
            'name' => 'product_id',
            'value' => '$data->product_detail->product_name',
        ),
          array(
            'header' => 'Qty',
            'name' => 'product_id',
            'value' => '$data->product_detail->quantity',
        ),
             array(
            'header' => 'product_id',
            'name' => 'product_id',
            'value' => '$data->product_detail->product_id',
        ),
        // 'representative_name',
        'email',
        // 'password',
        'mobile',




            array(
                    'header' => 'Image',
                    'name' => 'u_id',
                    'id'=>'u_id',

                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'filter'=>array('1'=>"Recomonded",'2'=>"Related"),      
          ),




        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Comment: Reproduce your problem with html  otherwise you haven't any problem in code and no one able to help you ?

Comment: using this code and a select element named Vendor I get the alert showing each time I change the select box.  Are there any issues showing in console - what does your HTML look like? and are you clearing the alert each time?

Comment: Yii GridView has a lot of it's own client side code to handle different events, your problem could come from there. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: can you add the code for the select menu from the html source using inspector?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the gridview is loading new html using ajax.
If that's the case, then your event listeners won't be attached to the new replacement `select` elements.

Why not use the commented out `.on()` method?

Move back to delegated events:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).on('change', 'select[name="Vendor"]', function(){

    if(this.value ==2){
        jQuery('.grid_data').show();
    }else{
        jQuery('.grid_data_rel').show();
    }
});
```